# Oracle Version Mismatch

Tags: c#, oracle

I have written a code in `C#` which uses Oracle version `11.0.2`. While deploying the code in server, which uses Oracle version `10.0.2`, it throws an

> error :
>   "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

In the server, will installing an oracle version 11.0.2 solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using a Nuget or global install?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about Oracle version 10.2 - this is about 20 year old and out of support for long time.

I assume you don't have installed "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" (ODP.NET) at all. The standard Oracle Instant Client does not include ODP.NET by default. You can download ODP.NET from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

Ensure that you download the correct version. The architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) must match architecture from your application and installed Oracle client. The version also have to match even the minor version number is important!

**Update**

The error message is *Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.121.2.0 ...*

So, apparently you have ODP.NET version 2.121.2.0 installed but according to your statement the Oracle client is version 10.2 (version 10.0.2 does not exist)

As I already mentioned these versions have to match. ODP.NET version 10.2.0.2 is not available anymore for download.

Thus you have to [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)/install Oracle Instant Client version 12.1.0.2.0

Of course, you can remove all ODP.NET and Oracle Client versions and re-install desired versions.

In general it does not matter on which version you developed your application, unless you [disabled Publisher Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/publisherpolicy-element). The deplyed application should load any installed version of ODP.NET automatically.

Comment: Yes... Am sure the version is 10.2 and the code i have built on my desktop it uses 11.2,